# Proto Buffers not storing data in readable format

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers

I am saving my protobuf messages to file and the format is all messed.  I have seen it done before where the protobug messages would be saved to disk in near the same format as the .proto file.  I am doing it like:

```
using (Stream output = File.OpenWrite(@"logs\listings.txt"))
{          
    listingBook.AddClisting(_listing);
    listingBook.Build().WriteTo(output);
}
```

But what I get is a mangled file that seems ENTER separated with strange tags. What I want it to look like when it is saved to disk is like the example:

```
# Textual representation of a protocol buffer.
# This is *not* the binary format used on the wire.
person {
  name: "John Doe"
  email: "jdoe@example.com"
}
```

Comment: If you want JSON, use a JSON serializer...  Proto Buffers are not meant to be human readable.

Answer (score 6):

Pay more attention to the comment

> This is *not* the binary format used on the wire.

Protobuf messages are not designed to be human-readable.  Storing them in a text file makes no sense; they are not text.

Answer (score 1):

The primary protobuf encoding format is binary. There *is* a secondary text format exposed by some implementations, but it kinda loses a lot of the advantages of protobuf, and library support for it is patchy (if it is even formally defined). I would say: if you want human readable, use XML or json. Not protocol buffers.

Answer (score 1):

Using PrintTo instead of WriteTo keeps the data in a readable format.  Finally found it.

Answer (score 0):

As protobuf is intended to be fast, binary compatible and optimal;Messages stored as human readable is mostly out of the question. There is the [JSONFormatter Utility](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp/class/google/protobuf/json-formatter) however:

It's primary purpose is that of what you asked for, but be aware that this probably makes everything significantly slower; While adding some overhead because of the conversion.